# Take data from user in mongoDB from separate file

Tags: mongodb

How can I insert record into database from taking values from user dynamically.
Here is what I am trying to achieve

```
mongo database filename.js
```

in the filename.js I have following code

```
takedata() //e.g. scanf()
let obj = {};
obj.name = takenData;
db.collection.insert(obj);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `takenData `? Is it come from DB or from the third party?

Comment: @HardikShah  `char str[100]; scanf("%s", &str);` similar to this line of code i assumed there is takedata() function in mongo and it will take data from user.. that data is takenData;

Comment: any one? pls help me.